# How to wrap text of column header when using table_print gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have few large columns names in my table which are being truncated and not fully shown. they are being show as **AVERAGE_COMPLETED_TASKS_PER_...** whereas I would like to wrap the text to next line and not get truncated.

[table_print](https://github.com/arches/table_print)

Answer (score 1):

Default max width is 30 characters. You need to change it. More info
[here](https://github.com/arches/table_print/blob/master/lib/table_print/config.rb). 
In console you have to write this:

```
tp.max_width= 200
```

Comment: this wont wrap the text